# AWS SDK Route53: trying to create A record, but getting generic InvalidInputException: Invalid request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

Can someone help me with this generic exception? Any ideas? Up to this point AWS messages were very helpful, but now I am stuck.

```
com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.InvalidInputException: Invalid request (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput; Request ID: UUID)
```

I already fixed permission problems. The javadoc of withTTL says "If you're creating or updating an alias resource record set, omit TTL. Amazon Route 53 uses the value of TTL for the alias target.", but the alias target does not offer such a method.

```
 AmazonRoute53 route53 = AmazonRoute53ClientBuilder.standard() //
    .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1) // I thought Route53 is region-independent?
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)))
    .build();

AliasTarget aliasTarget = new AliasTarget() //
    .withHostedZoneId(HOSTED_ZONE_ID) //
    .withEvaluateTargetHealth(false) //
    .withDNSName("1.2.3.4"); // using a valid IP here

ResourceRecordSet recordSet = new ResourceRecordSet() //
    .withType(RRType.A) //
    .withName("sub.domain.com") // using my own domain here
    .withTTL(300L) //
    .withAliasTarget(aliasTarget);

Change change = new Change() //
    .withAction(ChangeAction.UPSERT) //
    .withResourceRecordSet(recordSet);

route53.changeResourceRecordSets(new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest() //
    .withHostedZoneId(HOSTED_ZONE_ID) //
    .withChangeBatch(new ChangeBatch().withChanges(change)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I finally figured it out. I was doing it all wrong, no alias target needed (API lured me down that alley).

```
AmazonRoute53 route53 = AmazonRoute53ClientBuilder.standard() //
    .withRegion(REGION) //
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)))
    .build();

ResourceRecordSet recordSet = new ResourceRecordSet() //
    .withType(RRType.A) //
    .withName("sub.domain.com") //
    .withTTL(300L) //
    .withResourceRecords(new ResourceRecord().withValue("1.2.3.4"));

Change change = new Change() //
    .withAction(ChangeAction.UPSERT) //
    .withResourceRecordSet(recordSet);

route53.changeResourceRecordSets(new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest() //
    .withHostedZoneId(HOSTED_ZONE_ID) //
    .withChangeBatch(new ChangeBatch().withChanges(change)));
```

Comment: Alias target would be used if, instead of a literal, static A record, you wanted an A record that mirrored whatever the value of another A record is.  This is commonly used when the target is CloudFront, S3, or ELB.  These services don't give you an IP address to point to... and since the alias target zone pays the query bills, any hostnames pointing to those services are effectively free when you use an Alias.  It can also point to another name in the same zone, similar to a CNAME but usable where a CNAME isn't.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Good to know.

Comment: Aliases can also come in handy if you have a complex dns routing configuration, where you are laying lbr/geo and potentially elb/cf and want to hide that complexity from clients.  I like to think of it as a pointer to another record, server side cname’s.